# For every $X\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$, there is a smooth vector field on $M\times N$ that is $F$-related to $X$

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds

> Let $M$, $N$ be smooth manifolds, and let $f:M\to N$ be a smooth map.
> Define $F : M\to M \times N$ by $F(x) = (x, f(x) )$. Show that for every smooth vector field
> $V$ of $M$ , there is a smooth vector field on $W$ on $M \times N$ that is $F$-related to $V$.

The question is already [posted and answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3857640/668308). I think it's essentially the same argument but I wonder if there's a problem in this argument because it's relatively short:
Note that the graph $\Gamma_f$ of the function $f$ is a properly embedded submanifold of $M\times N$. In particular, it's closed in $M\times N$. Also, $F:M\to\Gamma_f$ is a diffeomorphism so if $X$ is a smooth vector field on $M$ then its pushforward $F_*(X)$ can be defined on $\Gamma_f$ which is smooth and by extension lemma, there is a vector field on $M\times N$ which is an extension of $F_*(X)$. Clearly $F$-related to $X$ by construction.